# Coincidence of Lie Algebra and Lie Subgroup

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

[Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lie_algebra_of_an_analytic_group) says:

> The Lie algebra of an intersection of Lie subgroups coincides with the intersection of their Lie algebras.

I want to prove this statement. Namely, $T_I (A\cap B)=T_I A \cap T_I B$, where $A$ and $B$ are closed subgroups of $GL_n$.

From definitions, it seems trivial. But how can I write a rigorous proof for it? Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a Lie group, let $\mathfrak g$ and let $H$ be a Lie subgroup of $G$. Then$$\mathfrak{h}=\left\{X\in\mathfrak{g}\,\middle|\,(\forall t\in\mathbb{R}):\exp(tx)\in H\right\}$$is the Lie algebra of $H$. Using this, it's quite easy. If $X\in\mathfrak g$, then asserting that $X$ belongs to the Lie algebra of $A\cap B$ means that$$(\forall t\in\mathbb{R}):\exp(tX)\in A\cap B,$$which, of course, is equivalent to$$(\forall t\in\mathbb{R}):\exp(tX)\in A\wedge(\forall t\in\mathbb{R}):\exp(tX)\in B.$$And clearly this means that $X\in\mathfrak{a}\cap\mathfrak b$.

Comment: For the last line of your answer, do you mean $"(\forall t\in R): exp(tX)\in A"$ implies $"X\in \mathfrak{a}"$? I only know another direction is true. Could you please explain it? Is this actually a "if and only if" statement?

Comment: Also, @GiuseppeNegro pointed out, "With the usual definitions, exp(tX)∈G only for t in a neighborhood of 0." See [another related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685901/exponential-and-lie-algebra#2685901).

Comment: @ChunjingGU Yes, it is a “if and only if” statement. See the first two sentences of my answer.

Comment: Is your answer indeed a general proof of "The Lie algebra of an intersection of Lie subgroups coincides with the intersection of their Lie algebras"? Not only in matrices case?

Comment: @Lam18373 Since I made no mention whatsoever to matrices…