# Exponential and Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-algebras, exponentiation

Let $G$ be a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, and $\mathfrak{g}$ be its Lie algebra. In other words, $\mathfrak{g}=T_I G$.  We know if $X\in \mathfrak{g}$, then $\exp(tX)\in G$ for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

I am wondering whether another direction is correct, namely:

if $\exp(tX)\in G$ for any $t\in \mathbb{R}$, then $X\in \mathfrak{g}$.

It sounds correct, and I actually need it to prove [a statement on the intersection of Lie algebras](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2685750/coincidence-of-lie-algebra-and-lie-subgroup). Could anyone help me check whether the above direction is correct or not? If this direction is actually incorrect, can anyone give me a hint on how to prove the statement in the link?

Comment: how do you define $\frak g$?

Comment: I have actually seen your reverse direction used as the definition of $\mathfrak{g}$ (for example on page 4 here http://www4.ncsu.edu/~aalexan3/articles/liegroups.pdf)

Comment: As Pliny says everything depends on how you define $\mathfrak g$. With the usual definitions, $\exp(tg)\in G$ only for $t$ in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: @Plinytheill As I mentioned in the question, $\mathfrak{g}$ is the lie algebra of $G$. That is, the tangent space of $G$ at $I$.

Comment: I guess the only potential subtlety is showing $t\mapsto exp(tX)$ is smooth as a map into $G$. For this you may have to use a theorem about how theres a chart at the identity for which $G$ maps to level sets -- or maybe you've already proved this fact. After that, this is just a fact about smooth paths in sub manifolds: their derivatives are contained in the tangent spaces of the submanifold. I guess you also need to know that $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}exp(tX) = X$.

Comment: @Plinytheill Thanks a lot! Your comment is very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to observe that $t\mapsto\exp(tX)$ is a smooth curve in $M_n(\mathbb R)$ and its derivative at $0$ is $X$. So if the curve has values in $G$, then by definition its derivative at $0$ lies in $\mathfrak g$. (So it would be sufficient, that the values lie in $G$ in some neighborhood of $0$.)